# Fine tuning a find and replace code

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have this code that works to find the word “Yes” and replace it with a 1.  How do I also add in a line for it to find “No” and replace it with a 0?

```
function fandr() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r=s.getDataRange();
  var vlst=r.getValues();
  var i,j,a,find,repl;
  find="Yes"
  repl="1"
  for (i in vlst) {
    for (j in vlst[i]) {
      a=vlst[i][j];
      if (a==find) vlst[i][j]=repl;
    }
  }
  r.setValues(vlst);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll do you one better!

```
function fandr(params) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getDataRange();
  var vlst = r.getValues();
  var i,j,replace;

  for (i in vlst) {
    for (j in vlst[i]) {
      replace = params[vlst[i][j]];
      if(replace != undefined) {
        vlst[i][j] = replace;
      }
    }
  }

  r.setValues(vlst);
}
```

It's always best to write code in such away that the behavior can be changed in the future. This has been rewritten such that it can find and replace anything and everything you tell it to by passing in an object as the parameter.

You would call it using

```
fandr({"Yes":1, "No":0})
```

Alright, alright, I get it, that's not exactly what you were asking. The answer to your question is simple, use the "else if" statement

```
function fandr() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getDataRange();
  var vlst = r.getValues();
  var i,j, a;

  for (i in vlst) {
    for (j in vlst[i]) {
      a = vlst[i][j];
      if(a == "Yes") vlst[i][j] = 1;
      else if(a == "No") vlst[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }

  r.setValues(vlst);
}
```